# Wild card matching pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

OCaml provides wild card matching pattern when every other case fails:

```
let imply v = match v with 
         (true,false) -> false
       |   _          -> true;;
```

What's the equivalence in Haskell?

Comment: It does. You're doing something wrong. Actual code please, then we may actually say something useful about what you're doing wrong. If you're matching on (true,false) in haskell you have to realize _that_ doesn't work, because true and false are variable names, not literals in haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better separate the function definition, like this

```
imply :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool
imply (True, False) = False
imply _ = True
```

Now, whenever the pattern `(True, False)` is passed to `imply`, it will return `False`, on all other cases it will return `True`.

Also, what you have actually done is perfectly fine, if you are defining it in interactive shell, better watch out for the indentation errors.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let imply v = case v of
Prelude|              (True, False) -> False
Prelude|              _ -> True
Prelude| :}
Prelude> imply (False, True)
True
Prelude> imply (True, False)
False
Prelude> imply (True, True)
True
Prelude> imply (False, False)
True
```